# Getting Frequency of Audio - Android

Tags: audio, fft, android

Ok, so i'm trying to make an app which graphs the audio of music playing on my phone, I'm able to get the music playing and stuff but after that is where i run into problems. I know that I would use FFT to get assist me in doing this but when ever I look at anyones implementations of FFT it just confuses me, would anyone be able to help me understand how to implement this?

At the moment I'm just hard coding in a test.wav file to play on startup using,

```
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test2);
mPlayer.setLooping(true);
mPlayer.start();
```

I think from here I need to get the audio into an array of bytes and then feed it into some sort of FFT method, any assistance, sorry if this seems like a bit much i'm really new to android development but quite curious as to how this would work. At the moment i'm probably only going to display the numeric value of the frequency rather than graph it, the graphing should be relatively easy though once I'm able to get the frequency.

Comment: Why not use the [Visualizer class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html) ?

Comment: Perhaps because that wouldn't lead to learning.   You have several challenges - obtaining entire samples from an audio file, windowing, calculating an FFT (or DFT), preparing the result for meaningful presentation.

Comment: The stated goal was just to "make an app which graphs the audio of music playing on my phone". Unless there are additional requirements that the OP hasn't mentioned, I still see no reason not to use the Visualizer class.